# Hash tables runtime complexity for chaining with 2 hash function

Tags: python-2.7, data-structures, hash, hashmap

This question deal with collision based in a new approach for chaining in hash tables.

There is 2 hash functions: First function `h1(x) = x mod m1`
with this function all the items are hashed to the primary hash table.
inside each index for the primary hash table there is internal hash table that hash the key with function 2 : `h2(x) = x mod m2` and `(m1!=m2)`

for example lets say i had m1 = 5 and m2 = 3
and i want to insert 2 .. h1(2) = 2 mod 5 = 2 and h2(2) = 2 mod 3=2 
this mean 2 will be inserted in the second index in the primary table in the second index of the internal table.

when collision happen in the primary table (this mean h1(x)=x%m1= y%m1 =h1(y)) we going to the second hash function h2 and calculate h2(x) and h2(y) and we put each one in the corresponding index in the internal hash table. lets say h1(x)= x%5 and h2(x) = x%3 for example if we insert 7 and 12 we will get h1(7)=2 and h1(12)=2 this mean both will be in index 2 in the primary hash table. then we compute h2 for both ( h2(7) = 1 and h2(12)=0) which mean we put 7 in index 1 and 12 in index 0 in the internal table.(and by this we avoid collision)

this was the question in the exams, also first section about the question was if there is collision for this numbers - 0 5 15 17 (with m1=5 and m2=3) and there is obviously 0 and 15 have the modulo for 5 and 3. the second question was about the search worst case runtime complexity? and the third section was to give 5 numbers that make the worst case if we search for number 2 in the tablewhen collision happen in the primary table (this mean h1(x)=x%m1= y%m1 =h1(y)) we going to the second hash function h2 and calculate h2(x) and h2(y) and we put each one in the corresponding index in the internal hash table. lets say h1(x)= x%5 and h2(x) = x%3 for example if we insert 7 and 12 we will get h1(7)=2 and h1(12)=2 this mean both will be in index 2 in the primary hash table. then we compute h2 for both ( h2(7) = 1 and h2(12)=0) which mean we put 7 in index 1 and 12 in index 0 in the internal table.(and by this we avoid collision)

this was the question in the exams, also first section about the question was if there is collision for this numbers - 0 5 15 17 (with m1=5 and m2=3) and there is obviously 0 and 15 have the modulo for 5 and 3. the second question was about the search worst case runtime complexity? and the third section was to give 5 numbers that make the worst case if we search for number 2 in the table

the question is what is the search worst case runtime complexity?
and example for 5 numbers that can cause worst case if we search for number 2.

i think the complexity is o(1) and i used this 5 numbers
7 12 17 22 42

did this correct ?can anybody help with this!

Comment: How do you resolve collisions in the internal hash tables?

Comment: with hash function number 2 
h2(x) = x mod m2 
the definition for collision here is if h1(x)=h1(y) and h2(x)=h2(y) and x!=y

Comment: Let me try to ask in another way - what do you do when a collision occurs?

Comment: when collision happen in the primary table (this mean h1(x)=x%m1= y%m1 =h1(y))
we going to the second hash function h2 and calculate h2(x) and h2(y) and we put each one in the corresponding index in the internal hash table.

lets say h1(x)= x%5 and h2(x) = x%3
for example if we insert 7 and 12  we will get h1(7)=2 and h1(12)=2 this mean both will be in index 2 in the primary hash table. then we compute h2 for both ( h2(7) = 1 and h2(12)=0) which mean we put 7 in index 1 and 12 in index 0 in the internal table.(and by this we avoid collision)

Comment: What happens if there is a collision in the secondary table?

Comment: nothing. it's will be a collision like i say h1(x)=h1(y) and h2(x)=h2(y) and x!=y

Comment: "Nothing" is not a valid hash table collision resolution strategy.

Comment: my friend the question was not if it valid or not. did you have any idea about the solutions for the questions?

Comment: Let me try to explain again - by "not valid", I mean your question isn't well formed; it isn't complete; it doesn't make sense yet. The reason is that collision handling is the core question of hash table performance. If you assume no collisions occur, then yes, any hash table has O(1) performance, but this misses the whole point of asking about hash table performance.

Comment: Additionally, without specifying the collision resolution strategy, it is astronomically unlikely that such a hash table could be constructed. I don't mean that it is difficult, I mean that, for almost all sets of keys and almost all hash functions, collisions will occur. Since the object can't be constructed, asking about it's query time is not a well-formed question.

Comment: this was the question in the exams, also first section about the question was if there is collision for this numbers - 0 5 15 17 (with m1=5 and m2=3)
and there is obviously 0 and 15 have the modulo for 5 and 3.

the second question was about the search worst case runtime complexity?
and the third section was to give 5 numbers that make the worst case if we search for number 2 in the table.